# RxJava - making two calls where the first one is conditional

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava 2 to do API's calls.
I have to do a call to cancel the booking of a class.

But I must have to do or not one previous call to get missing information.

It's something like this:

```
if classId not exists
   get classId
   then unbook class
else
   unbook class
```

I don't want to repeat the unbook class code.

Here are the code simplified:

```
FitnessDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(FitnessDataService.class);
        // if we don't have the aid of class (reserved), we get it from the reserved classes


        if (fitClass.getAid() == null) {
            service.getReservedClasses(FitHelper.clientId)
                    .flatMap(reservedClasses ->
                    {
                        // get the class ID from reserved classes
                         ...
                        return service.unbookClass(fitClass.getAid());
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(response -> {
                                // success
                            }, err -> 
                                // error
        } else {
            service.unbookClass(fitClass.getAid())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(response -> {
                                // success
                            }, err -> 
                                // error
        }
```

As you can see, the service.unbookClass is repeated.
How I can call always this service.unbookClass and only call the service.getReservedClasses if I don't have the class id (fitClass.getAid() == null)
without repeating the code to the second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest separating the actual source of the id into its own separate observable. Maybe something like:

```
Observable<Long> idObservable;
if (fitClass.getAid() == null) {
    idObservable = service.getReservedClasses(FitHelper.clientId)
        .map({ reservedClasses ->
            /* Get the Id and do stuff with it */
            return fitClass.getAid();
        });
} else {
    idObservable = Observable.just(fitClass.getAid());
}

idObservable.flatMap({ aid -> service.unbookClass(aid) })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* TODO */);
```

Comment: I have implemented this and works well. Thank you :)
Just changed the .map to .flatMap because I only want get one value from the reservedClasses list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good use for [`Maybe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) and `switchIfEmpty`.  The `fromCallable` method will return 1 value if the returned value is non-null, and just complete if the item returned is `null`.  `switchIfEmpty` can be used to provide an alternate (Single or Maybe in this case) if the source did not emit an item.  Asuming your retrofit call to `unbookClass` is returning a single, your code would look something like --

```
Maybe.fromCallable(() -> fitClass.getAid())
    .switchIfEmpty(service.getReservedClasses(FitHelper.clientId)
                    .flatMap(reservedClasses -> {
                        // ....
                        return fitClass.getAid());
                    }))
    .flatMap(id -> service.unbookClass(id))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thank you to get me know the Maybe operator and the `switchIfEmpty`. Although, I'm with some trouble to implement this. My retrofit call to `unbookClass` returns a Observable (`Observable<ArrayList<FitStatus>>`). Is it simple to adapt?

Comment: yes, just return `Single<ArrayList<FitStatus>>` in your retrofit interface.  Most retrofit calls only return one element and then call `onComplete`, which is the same as a `Single`

Comment: Thank you. I changed my retrofit calls to return `Maybe` and this way, this approach works well. I think that I could also continue using the `Observable` and than convert to `Maybe` using the `.singleElement()`